# How do I fish wire through a suspended ceiling without getting stuck on joists?

Tags: wiring, data-wiring

I'd like to run some ethernet cable in my wall through a suspended ceiling to a room where I can terminate the cable. I've not done this before. Most videos show DIYers up in their attic with ample space to grab and pull a wire. I do not have that luxury. I can't fit in the space. How do I get my cable up the wall and then pulled 12 feet through that space without getting stuck on one of the joists?

[image: Space between ceiling and floor above. Joists are at the top of the photo]

Comment: Does https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/267173/135381 help?

Comment: Miss the olden days.  When you could just have some candy and bring a little helper home.   These days the candy will get you a swat team.

Comment: This one looks perfect for the R/C rock crawler method. :)

Answer (score 4):

use a flexible rod with a kink in the end that allows it to ski over obstacles

when I was doing satellite TV  installs I used 1/2" pvc conduit for this task.